# The PHP code is not allowing the fields below the code to fill in data

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

This makes no sense. Down where I have  This is a drop down that adds the selected section to the option and fills in all the rest of the options from MySQL with PDO. My problem is that when all the fields are being filled in it only fills in the fields above the select box. All the fields below are not filled in. If I remove the code for the drop down every field is filled in. This is strange. I have only included a portion of the HTML code because it is quit long. Does anybody no why this would happen?

```
<?php
$sid = $_GET["sid"];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM signings WHERE id = '$sid'";
$stmt = $db->query($sql); 
$row =$stmt->fetchObject();
$custid = $row->customer;
?>

<div class="container center col-md-9">
    <form action="formpross.php" id="testForm" method="post" class="form-horizontal" role="form">
        <div class="row well well-lg">


            <div class="col-md-4">
                <label for="signdate" class="control-label">
                    SignStart:
                </label>

                    <input name="signstart" id="datetimepicker" type="text" class="form-control input-sm" value="<?php echo $row->signstart;?>">


            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <label for="signend"class="control-label">
                    SignEnd:
                </label>

                    <input name = "signend" id="datetimepicker1" type="text" class="form-control input-sm"value="<?php echo $row->signend;?>">




            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <label for="customer" class="control-label">
                    Customer: 
                </label>



// THIS IS WHERE THE CODE THAT SEAMS TO BE CASING THE PROBLEM IS  
    <select name="customers"id="customer" class="form-control input-sm">
    <?php
              $result = $db->query("SELECT custid, name FROM customers WHERE pid = $pid");
              foreach($result as $row)
              {
                  echo '<option value="'.$row['custid'].'"';
                  if($row['custid']==$custid)
                  {
                      echo ' selected';
                  }
                  echo '>'. $row['name'] . '</option>'."\n";
              }
     ?>
    </select>

  // THIS IS WHERE THE CODE THAT SEAMS TO BE CASING THE PROBLEM ENDS 



            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <label  for="contact" class="control-label">
                    Contact:
                </label>
                <input name="contact"  class="form-control input-sm" id="contact"value="<?php echo $row->contact;?>">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">

                <label  for="samount" class="control-label">Signing Amount:</label>
                <input  name="samount"   class="form-control input-sm"  id="samount"value="<?php echo $row->samount;?>">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">

                <label  for="prtamount" class="control-label">Printing Amount:</label>
                <input   name="prtamount"   class="form-control input-sm" id="prtamount" value="<?php echo $row->prtamount;?>" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="What you charge for printing">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">

                <label  for="ordern" class="control-label">
                    Order #:
                </label>
                <input name="ordern"  class="form-control input-sm" id="order#" value="<?php echo $row->ordern;?>">
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually, it makes perfect sense. You're overwriting your variable at the top of the page.

You define `$row`:

```
$row = $stmt -> fetchObject();
```

Then, in your select `foreach` loop you're redefining `$row`:

```
foreach($result as $row) { ... }
```

Simple fix, change the variable in the foreach to something else such as:

```
foreach($result as $options) { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

In the loop for your dropdown, you loop using a variable called `$row`. Then, further down, you try to pre-populate values with `$row` again, thinking it's the same `$row` defined at the top.

Just rename `$row` to something else and this should work. Example:

```
// Before:
foreach($result as $row)

// After:
foreach($result as $dropDownRow)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot I stared at this for 2 hours. Never saw that. Sometimes it just takes a second set of eyes

Comment: No problem @user3326386. You might want to mark this or SeanWM's answer as accepted, to guide anyone else who has a similar issue in the future :)